# Restrict MousePosition to specific Graphics object

Tags: graphics, dynamic

I have a problem using `MousePosition`. I want to restrict the value returned by `MousePosition` to a specific Graphics object. Consider the following example:

```
g1 = Graphics[{Green, Disk[]}]; 
g2 = Graphics[{Blue,Disk[]}];
{g1, g2, Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics"]]}
```

I would like to have the mouse position updated only if the mouse is on the second (blue) disk and not on the first one (green). This seems to be an easy problem, but I can't figure out how it works in *Mathematica*.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
g1 = Graphics[{Green, Disk[]}];
g2 = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}];
{g1, Mouseover[g2, Dynamic@(mp = MousePosition["Graphics"]; g2)], Dynamic@mp}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

I have overlooked the example in the help for `MousePosition`

```
Graphics[Disk[Dynamic[MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}, {0, 0}]]],
  PlotRange -> 10, ImageSize -> 100]
```

With that the value returned by `MousePosition` is restricted to the `Graphics` object it is associated with.